Trying to open my index.html file on localhost Go server
I'm trying to figure out how to feed my server my own index.html file. I have the server running on a localhost, but I can't find out how to get it to take in an HTML file I have in the directory. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is not for anything serious, just trying to learn Go.
I haven't tried much except looking around for a way, and so far, no luck.

You should show us your code.  The issue is that it's all up to YOU.  You will receive a request for "/", for example, and in the handler for that route, you open up the file, read it, and store the contents in the response.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

“I haven't tried much …”, asking on StackOverflow should be after you have tried to research the problem. This is not a support forum, questions should be researched and well formed.

A HTML file is a text file and to read a whole text file into a go program there is os.ReadFile about which you should read at least the go by example page at https://gobyexample.com/reading-files where you will find a code example.
The official documentation is here: https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile
There you can find that os.ReadFile does not give you a string but rather a []byte which you can easily turn into a string using the string() function.
The more usual case will be reading and working with HTML templates. The standard library has this package: https://pkg.go.dev/html/template  -- but you should really search for introductory texts about it rather then "just" reading the documentation.

note: string is not a function, it's a type and the syntax string(value) is a type conversion.

@JimB Noted. That explains, why I could not find it as a function. Thanks for the clarification.
